# eBay API/XML issues with slashes and htmlentities

Tags: html, ebay-api, stripslashes

I setup a local server using EasyPHP 5.3.8.1 - on it, I wrote a bunch of eBay API/XML stuff to post items to eBay. Everything works perfectly when using my local server. However, when I upload the php files to my webspace, when submitting the items to eBay, htmlentities are added and some slashes are added into the code and it ruins the offsite image URIs and font stylings...

I simply don't understand why my server sends everything through without an issue, but my webserver does not.

When I go to revise the item in eBay, it shows this in the html ... note all the htmlentities, slashes, and whatnot... how can I make sure this does not happen? Again, it does not happen when I use my local machine server, only the uploaded version does this...

```
<font face="\&quot;Trebuchet" ms\"="">
<center><img src="\&quot;http://claimthis.com/images/WELCOME!.gif\&quot;"><br><br>
<font size="+3"><b>
Seagate Barracuda 80GB 7200RPM 2MB Buffer Hard Drive Internal Desktop 3.5 inch
</b></font>
<br><br>
<img src="\&quot;http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/3btech_2189_53809317\&quot;"   style="\&quot;max-width:" 450px;="" border:6px="" ridge="" #0099ff;\"="">
<br><br>
<center><img src="\&quot;http://claimthis.com/images/DETAILS.gif\&quot;"></center><br>
<table><tbody><tr><td><img src="\&quot;http://images.3btech.net/ct/Top-    Rated.jpg\&quot;" height="100px">
</td><td><b><center><font size="+2">Buy with confidence!</font></center></b><br> 
</td><td><img src="\&quot;http://images.3btech.net/ct/PlatinumPS.gif\&quot;">
```

I did even try these to get rid of entities and slashes... the top line was in there to ensure UTF-8 compliance, which was a pain in the ass itself... the second was a last ditch effort before posting here...

```
$desc = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$desc);
$desc = stripslashes($desc)
```

Doesn't make any sense right? Any help would be most appreciated...

Comment: I should have noted this before, but for whatever reason \&quot; is being added around all URIs ... but why? I should have titled this PHP as well.. terrible first question post... heh.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had nothing to do with my servers or setup. I believe I modified the uploaded file then overwrote with the wrong local file.

I was not passing the correct variable to from one page to the next, so 'stripslashes' was not stripping slashes from anything real. Simple mistake that I overlooked and should have caught last week...